# How to slow XAMPP down to more easily measure page timing?

Tags: xampp, timing

I'm trying to test some custom page timing code which times PHP execution time, SQL query time and the time the browser actually takes to render the page to the client.

How can I slow XAMPP down so page loads take a few seconds, so I can more easily measure timing?

Comment: I would instead vary the data retrieved from sql server and the number of renderable controls on your page, 10, 1000, 10k, 100k 1M records for example, plottable on a chart to see what the relationship is likely to be.

Comment: The part I'm really interested is the page render time. This could highlight a slow network rather than a server hosting the PHP/SQL

Comment: add loads of renderable controls then :)

Comment: What do you mean Chris? If possible I would like to implement something on XAMPP to simulate a slow network.